# PrintWriter Object in Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When we use Console writing then ***out*** object is accessed through ***System*** class
but while using servlets printWriter object is used instead of ***PrintStream*** Class object?

Comment: The question is incomprehensible. Please correct your grammar and punctuation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because we are not writing on the `System` and are writing on a web page. 
Here is what javadoc says

PrintWrtier

> Unlike the PrintStream class, if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output. These methods use the platform's own notion of line separator rather than the newline character

Answer (score 0):

Because we are writing it to display on web page.

Comment: I know this but functionality of both are near about same so why new extra class is created

Answer (score 0):

Why because there is difference between writing to console and a web browser

The [writer attached to response object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29),

> Returns a PrintWriter object that can send character text to the client. **The PrintWriter uses the character encoding returned by getCharacterEncoding()**. If the response's character encoding has not been specified as described in getCharacterEncoding (i.e., the method just returns the default value ISO-8859-1), getWriter updates it to ISO-8859-1.

Where as the Systems out attached `writer` does not do Unicode character conversions correctly.